# Cartesian Product of a Set with One Element and An Interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Today, my topology professor wrote the following on the board several times:

$$ \{0\} \times [-1, 1]$$

What exactly does this mean? Is it possible to rewrite this in set builder notation?

Comment: $\{(0,b):b\in[-1,1]\}$

Comment: You could visualize this as all points on the y-axis of the xy-plane such that $-1 \le y \le 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\{0}\}\times[-1,1]={\{(a,t):a\in{\{0}\}, t\in[-1,1]}\}={\{(0,t): -1 \leq t\leq 1}\} $

Answer (score 0):

So this means all the ordered pairs where the first term is $0$ and the second term is in $[-1,1]$.

So $(0,0.5)$ and $(0,-0.27)$ and $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ etc. are all points in the set but $(0.1, 0.75)$ is not.

In builder notation:

$\{0\}\times [-1,1] = \{(0,b)| -1\le b \le 1\}$.

Or $\{(a,b)| a=0; b\in[-1,1]\}$

Or  $\{(a,b)| a\in{0}; b\in[-1,1]\}$.

Although the first is, IMO, the most descriptive and explanitory, the last is a direct mechanical application of the definition of a cartesian product.

$A \times B = \{(a,b)|a\in A; b\in B\}$ so that would mean:

$\{0\}\times [-1,1] =\{(a,b)| a\in \{0\}; b\in [-1,1]\}$

and .... that's that.